# How to restrict an admin page, if the user is not superadmin?

Tags: user-roles, user-access, content-restriction, plugin-all-in-one-seo

I use the All In One Seo Pack on my multisite, but this plugin have admin pages, what is not fall under the rule what restrict the plugin pages from my users, so I using the `remove_cap( $cap );` about 'edit_plugins', 'install_plugins', 'upload_plugins', but this not solving my issue. I want restrict this pages on my network's subsites:

```
      wp-admin/admin.php?page=all-in-one-seo-pack%2Faioseop_class.php
      wp-admin/admin.php?page=all-in-one-seo-pack%2Fmodules%2Faioseop_performance.php
      wp-admin/admin.php?page=all-in-one-seo-pack%2Fmodules%2Faioseop_sitemap.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restrict any pages from your users with this code, you can know only an any part of the url. (The example restrict the all pages of AIOSP (so the all url-s on the backend what associated with the keys: all-in-one-seo-pack or aioseop) what are wriggle out of from the `remove_cap( 'edit_plugins', 'install_plugins', 'upload_plugins' );` rules):

```
 add_action( 'current_screen', 'restrict_screen' );
 function restrict_screen() {
      if ( is_admin() ) {
      if (is_super_admin()) 
      return;
      $current_screen = "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
      $find_restrict = 'all-in-one-seo-pack';
      $find_restrict2 = 'aioseop';
      $match = strpos( $current_screen, $find_restrict );
      $match2 = strpos( $current_screen, $find_restrict2 );
               if( $match == TRUE || $match2 == TRUE ) {
                //  wp_die('get out');
                $current_admin = get_admin_url() . 'index.php';
                header('Location: ' . $current_admin . '', true, 301);
                }
      }   
 }
```

If you want using this code to an another url, rewrite the $find_restrict, $find_restrict2 to your url's part keys or add new "find_restrict" to the code. This code redirect your users to their current site's backend index. (Or you can use the `wp_die('get out');`)

Answer (score 1):

To remove from the admin menu, you could use [remove_menu_page()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page):

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', function ( ) {
    if (is_super_admin()) 
      return;
    remove_menu_page();
    // or remove_submenu_page( ...
},99);
```

If for some reason the page still exists, it's just missing it's menu link, you could check the [get_current_screen()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen) to see if the page is being viewed, and prevent access:

```
add_action( 'admin_notices', function ( ) {
    if (is_super_admin()) 
      return;
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ($screen->parent_base == 'all-in-one-seo-pack') { // or wtv
        wp_die('get out');
    }
},99);
```

Comment: This good in most cases, but not working with the current (all-in-one-seo-pack) pages. Even so thanks, I wrote a code based on your answer.